# install sp 2013 on win7 sp1

Tags: sharepoint-server, windows-7, farm-setup, setup

i installing sp 2013 on win 7 sp1, sql 2012
when i run pre installation file, system show error
Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role: configuration error .

log file

> 2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Processor architecture is (9)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Common Startup
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Trying to remove the startup task if there is any.
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\SharePointServerPreparationToolStartup_0FF1CE14-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.cmd
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Error: Startup task doesn't exist. This is not a continuation after a restart.
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Locating the following command line arguments file:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - E:\PrerequisiteInstaller.Arguments.txt
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Error: This file does not exist
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Details of the current operating system: 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Major version number of the operating system:  (6)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Minor version number of the operating system:  (2)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Build number of the operating system:  (0X23F0=9200)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Major version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Minor version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Platform ID of the operating system:  (2)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Product suites available on the operating system:  (0)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Product type of the operating system:  (0)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Product type:  (1)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - OS type:  (0)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Configuring the application's property sheet...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Windows Management Framework 3.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - PowerShellVersion
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - 3.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - CTPVersion
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Could not find or unable to read CTPVersion key
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Install
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The value is (1)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Version
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - 4.5.50938
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - A post release .NET 4.5 is installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Identity Foundation\Setup\v3.5
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - 6.1.7600.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading version of the following file...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Synchronization\1.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The version is...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - 1.0.3010.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Version
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersion
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Windows Server AppFabric
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - ProductVersion
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Identity Extensions\Setup\1.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - 2.0.1459.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSIPC\CurrentVersion
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - 1.0.621.117
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Version
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - 5.0.51212.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB2671763)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - IsInstalled
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:13 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\KB2671763
>   2015-03-22 00:01:17 - Beginning download/installation
>   2015-03-22 00:01:17 - Created thread for installer
>   2015-03-22 00:01:17 - "C:\Windows\system32\ServerManagerCmd.exe" -inputpath "C:\Users\DucNA\AppData\Local\Temp\PreE5EB.tmp.XML"
>   2015-03-22 00:01:18 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
>   2015-03-22 00:01:18 - Install process returned (0X3EB=1003)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:18 - [In HRESULT format] (0X800703EB=-2147023893)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:18 - "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe" -i
>   2015-03-22 00:01:19 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
>   2015-03-22 00:01:20 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
>   2015-03-22 00:01:21 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
>   2015-03-22 00:01:22 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
>   2015-03-22 00:01:22 - Install process returned (0)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:22 - [In HRESULT format] (0)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:22 - "C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\iisext.vbs" /enext "ASP.NET v4.0.30319"
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Install process returned (1)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - [In HRESULT format] (-2147024895)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Error when enabling ASP.NET v4.0.30319
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Last return code (1)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Flags
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - PendingFileRenameOperations
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Error: The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role.
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Last return code (1)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Options for further diagnostics: 1. Look up the return code value 2. Download the prerequisite manually and verify size downloaded by the prerequisite installer. 3. Install the prerequisite manually from the given location without any command line options.
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Cannot retry
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Windows Management Framework 3.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - PowerShellVersion
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - 3.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - CTPVersion
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Could not find or unable to read CTPVersion key
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - The prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Install
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - The value is (1)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Version
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - 4.5.50938
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - A post release .NET 4.5 is installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Identity Foundation\Setup\v3.5
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - 6.1.7600.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - The prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading version of the following file...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Synchronization\1.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - The version is...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - 1.0.3010.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - The prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Version
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersion
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Windows Server AppFabric
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - ProductVersion
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Identity Extensions\Setup\1.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - 2.0.1459.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSIPC\CurrentVersion
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - 1.0.621.117
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following string value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Version
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - The value is... 
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - 5.0.51212.0
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB2671763)
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - IsInstalled
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - from the following registry location...
>   2015-03-22 00:01:23 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\KB2671763
>   2015-03-22 00:01:27 - Opening log file
>   2015-03-22 00:01:28 - Opened action for user
>   2015-03-22 00:01:28 - C:\Users\DucNA\AppData\Local\Temp\prerequisiteinstaller.2015.03.22-00.01.13.log

Answer (score 1):

I highly do not recommend you installing SharePoint 2013 on Windows 7 (SP1). You can find here the minimum software requirements for SharePoint 2013 : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#section4.

Comment: yes, but my machine is running with win7 sp1

Comment: You are Free to use hyperv to use a virtual server for this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the log file you provided is a little long to digest. It is unrecommended to use Windows 7, but still usable. I'd suggest following the installation steps listed on the following [site](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/08/21/guest-blog-by-jonas-nilsson-install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-8-1.aspx). It seems likely you haven't enabled one of the requisite windows features.

Likewise, if you want an easier method for installation, I'd advise using [AutoSPInstaller](https://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/). I've used it multiple times for installations (on Windows Server), but makes the installation a breeze.

I'm wishing you the best of luck!

Comment: I installed all steps in your link but can not resolve this problem :(

Comment: Are you still receiving the same errors logged?

Comment: The biggest thing that your log indicates, is two scenarios; you have pre-requisites installed that are up-to-date (and newer), and likewise, you are missing multiple pre-requisites.

Comment: yes, same errors.